# highcharts.js how to make double donut charts in one raw?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I use Highsharts to render my image. Now I want to make two donut charts in same row just like this one.

`jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/e2qpa/47/` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/e2qpa/47/)

I have try to set container's width,but can't achieve that result. Below demo is the area where I stucked in now. So who can give me some advice? Thanks in advance !

`jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lazybios/7nydybqa/`  [Demo-jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lazybios/7nydybqa/)

Comment: Why you cannot place charts in any table, or set CSS styles which will position divs as grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<div id="container2l" style="width:300px;height:400px;float:left"></div>
<div id="container2r" style="width:300px;height:400px;float:left"></div>
```

Note the 'float:left'